# How can I use arrayExists function when the array contains a null value?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a nullable array column in my table: Array(Nullable(UInt16)). I want to be able to query this column using arrayExists (or arrayAll) to check if it contains a value above a certain threshold but I'm getting an exception when the array contains a null value:

Exception: Expression for function arrayExists must return UInt8, found Nullable(UInt8)

My query is below where distance is the array column:

```
SELECT * from TracabEvents_ArrayTest
where arrayExists(x -> x > 9, distance);
```

I've tried updating the comparison in the lambda to "(isNotNull(x) and x > 9)" but I'm still getting the error. Is there any way of handling nulls in these expressions or are they not supported yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a condition to filter rows with empty list using notEmpty and assumeNotNull for x in arrayExists.

```
SELECT * FROM TracabEvents_ArrayTest WHERE notEmpty(distance) AND arrayExists(x -> assumeNotNull(x) > 9, distance)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I can't find any documentation on "assumeNotNull". Is it a new feature. I've been using this document, is it not up to date? http://clickhouse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_en.html

Comment: The only description I could find is here
[FunctionsNull](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Functions/FunctionsNull.h#L101)

Also in this doc you can find example of the usage of this function, but without description [https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/)

I am not sure from which version this function was introduced.
Have you tried this query on your installation?

Comment: Maybe I'll use that documentation in the future. It seems to be more up to date. Yes I've tried it on the version I'm using (version 1.1.54310) and it's working. Thanks